# SQL query syntax error near ''

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to use Magento theme and when I import the theme data I get an sql error that says

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2, query was: 

SELECT `#__cms_page`.* 
FROM `#__cms_page`
INNER JOIN `#__cms_page_store` AS `cms_page_store` 
    ON #__cms_page.page_id = cms_page_store.page_id 
WHERE (`#__cms_page`.`identifier`='home-demo-01') 
  AND (is_active = 1) 
  AND (cms_page_store.store_id IN (0, 1)) 
ORDER BY `cms_page_store`.`store_id` DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

I can't seems to find the problem as it says the syntax error is near nothing..

Comment: Always specify the RDBMS you are using. Is this MySQL?

Comment: "Magento theme" has nothing to do with SQL that I am aware of.  Are you using some sort of CMS software that is generating the query?

Comment: You're right, I edited and added the RDBMS. Also I just downloaded a theme for magento and upload the sample data from the sql file in the theme and those are  the names of the tables, I don't know if the theme uses a CMS software or not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not escaped the identifier reference in the ON clause.

i.e. you're missing backticks here:

```
ON  #__cms_page .page_id  = cms_page_store.page_id
   ^           ^
```

If we're going to escape identifiers, we prefer to do it *consistently*. My preference would be to assign a short alias to the table.  Also, the reference to `is_active` should be qualified... which table is that column coming from?

My tendency would be to write the query like this, and only escape the identifiers that actually need to be escaped:

```
  SELECT p.*
    FROM `#__cms_page` p
    JOIN `#__cms_page_store` s
      ON s.page_id = p.page_id
   WHERE ( p.identifier = 'home-demo-01' ) 
     AND ( p.is_active = 1 ) 
     AND ( s.store_id IN (0, 1) ) 
   ORDER BY s.store_id DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

If I was going to escape identifiers that don't need to be escaped, I would enclose *all* of them in backticks, everywhere.

Comment: OMG wow thank you! I didn't know there was a difference between backsticks and single quotes in SQL it does work with backsticks and not with single quotes

Comment: Thanks a lot, I would have done if it was my code (and I will from now on) but this is an automated code from a theme download..

Comment: @ShayMualem: a lot of the frameworks that generate SQL automatically escape every single identifier. Because it's pretty easy to do that. And it's never invalid to escape an identifier. And that's much simpler than going the route of figuring out if an identifier needs to be escaped or not, and doing that for every identifier. It's easier just escape them all.